# Are searches for APIs on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901279

Note that there are several API searches from 3 years ago that are still open, including [this Big List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6122505/102937) question.

Comment: Of course they are OT for exactly the reason you closed that question. The other question you mention, might just be locked, but isn't very popular though.

Comment: I don't see why requesting an API would be any sort of exception to our off-topic reason for recommendations. What makes them so special?

Comment: They're specifically code-related.  But yeah, I'm inclined to agree.  If it were a "Which class in the .net Framework do I use for..." question, it likely would have stayed open.

Comment: @RobertHarvey They are code related yes, but the close reason specifically includes ***software library***, which usually makes up an API.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Web services also have an API, which is what this person asked for.  His retort will be "well, the close reason doesn't say anything about web services."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Couldn't a web service be considered falling under the _offsite resource_ category? ;-) No I'm just kidding, I see you do your job very consciously and careful, including being concerned about the details.

Comment: I don't have a 'retort' as I stated in my comments I'm just looking for an answer to my question. I'm glad you guys got a good laugh out of it at least?. Meanwhile, I still don't have an answer to my original question :/

Comment: @Scott Your question is off topic for the given reason. It's arguable, if your comments there might be considered as a _retort_. The question is OT along the actual policies of SO though.

Comment: Only they weren't my comments, they were the hypothetical comment that Robert Harvey gave. My question was merely why was that question off topic when I specifically looked for similar questions before even asking the question (which exist and thus led me to ask the question to begin with) I wasn't trying to get my question in on a technicality and if it's off topic that's fine. Not sure how I was supposed to assume those questions were only there because they were old.

Comment: Maybe these data-API questions could go to Open Data.SE?  (Not a rhetorical question; I really don't know.)

Comment: Not only is is off-topic, it should be deleted as the tag is deprecated too.

Comment: What if the OP has done enough research to find list of some APIs, but he needs help to narrow it down? Shouldn't that be on-topic? It may help other readers in the future. Again, the argument could be opinion-based, but I still think its valuable? Any thoughts?

P.S. I looked at the Oscar question (linked) -> I think OP has done some research about it. In case, somebody knows an API which can do that, or, somebody knows variants of existing 'x' API, why not consider that as a valid question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you mean he does his job conscientiously, but he probably does it consciously as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ah, sorry, I was too quick to assume.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### On StackOverflow...

Asking for accessible APIs is just as problematic as asking for a recommendation of software.

The primary skill used for this is random familiarity or your favorite search engine.

Consider the hypothetical "Looking for a lunar phase api" question.  Well, if you know of one, you'd recommend it.  If you don't, you'd toss "json moon phase" into google and get back things like http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/astronomy which then would result in answers like:

> Try Weather Underground's API for astronomy at http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/astronomy

The reason that software recommendations are off topic here is because they generate crap answers.  Asking for APIs is no different in its likelihood of generating crap answers.

Therefore, it should remain off topic just like asking for a program to send arbitrary json requests would be.

#### Meanwhile, over at Software Recommendations...

Note that they are on topic on Software Recommendations.SE (Meta.SR.SE [Are web API recommendations on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/716/450)).  Given that they are on topic there, that would likely make them off topic anywhere where software recommendations are off topic.  See: [Free web API to query “Google” hits or similar](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1835/450) for an example API question on Software Recommendations.SE.

Answer (score 11):

I recognize the pattern, seen a lot of it lately.  Roughly categorized as the "Can you Google this for me?" questions.  Not uncommonly introduced with the "Does anybody know?" phrase.

Well, yes, pretty sure that Jon Skeet could google it.  Pretty sure he won't.

We've got a decent Off Topic selection reason for these questions.  Let's use it while it lasts.